# Generating multiple events in JSP page having more than one button

Tags: java, database, jsp, servlets, tags

I am a beginner in the JSP World as per I have noticed that, there is one form tag which has `action` and `method` attribute. In action tag we must write the URL of the servlet which gets activated after clicking the submit button.

But my problem start here. I am trying to develop a register page.

I have two servlets:

1. one checks for the availability of existing user,
2. second register the user.

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve it without a href link or image button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with your existing approach by registering a Javascript function

```
<body>    
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitType(submitType)
{
if(submitType==0)
    document.userForm.action="CheckUserAvailability.do";
else
    document.userForm.action="RegisterUser.do";
}
</script>
<form  name="userForm" method="post">
--Other elements here
<input type="submit" value="Check User Availabiliy" onClick="submitType(0)"/>
<input type="submit" value="Check User Availabiliy" onClick="submitType(1)"/>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Move the code that checks for availability of the existing user and register the user to its own service class say UserService. Make the form submit to 2nd servlet which uses UserService to perform both the operations.

You can have two separate forms but not nested forms in HTML. If you want a single form to change its actions (its target URL) depending on which submit is used, the only way you can achieve that is through javascript.

Comment: so i cannot have two submit button in one jsp page which can perform two different task

Comment: @CHANDRAHAS You can have two separate forms but not nested forms. If you want a single form to change its actions (its target URL) depending on which submit is used, the only way you can achieve that is through javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can.. In the action you give the Servlet name. and inside that servlet you can call java methods which are written in other classes.

Which means you can check

```
1.one checks for the availability of existing user
2.second register the user
```

Using two java classes(may be according to your choice)

Just call those methods with in the same servlet..Guess you got an idea.

Comment: Thanks Aruna I will try this idea two